# nginx/apache - хитрый редирект изображений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, редирект

Старый путь

```
https://site.com/pictures/202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70.jpg
```

Новый путь с подпапками двух уровней

```
https://site.com/p/20/2c/202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70.jpg
```

Как можно это сделать средствами htaccess или nginx?

Пока что остановился на создании регулярки
https://regex101.com/r/H0Flzp/1

Comment: А зачем делать редирект? Можно же просто отдать сразу картинку, вы же уже знаете какую и она лежит тут же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем редирект? Проще же сразу отдать картинку.

Например:

```
location /pictures/ {
    rewrite "/pictures/(([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})[0-9a-f]{28}\.\w+)$" "/p/$2/$3/$1";
}
```

Я тут заодно подправил регулярку, судя по виду это хеш, обычно в нём используются шестнадцатеричные цифры.

UPD: Исправил регулярное выражение. В первый раз забыл про расширение файла. https://regex101.com/r/H0Flzp/2

Comment: Спасибо, нет предела совершенству. У меня в вебмастере много обратных ссылок с картинками с 404 кодом. Подумал, что 301 как то переклеит ссылочный вес на новые